# No Route Matches on a Scoped Get Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm passing two params to a PATCH request and I get this error back from my test:

```
  1) Error:
ProjectsControllerTest#test_should_update_project:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:id=>nil, :profile_name=>#<Project id: 980190962, title: "MyString", user_id: 1, description: "MyText", created_at: "2013-12-11 15:20:00", updated_at: "2013-12-11 15:20:00">, :controller=>"projects", :action=>"show", :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'
```

I'm confused, because these tests worked in another app. Except this passes along a :profile_name param because the projects are scoped to a user.

```
  test "should update project" do
    sign_in :user, @user
    patch :update, id: @project, profile_name: @user, project: { description: @project.description, title: @project.title, user_id: @project.user_id }
    assert_redirected_to project_path(assigns(:project))
  end
```

Why is the test not receiving :id and :profile_name correctly?
The controller code works in browser, just not on the test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 test "should update project" do
    sign_in :user, @user
    patch :update, id: @project.id, profile_name: @user.name, project: { description: @project.description, title: @project.title, user_id: @project.user_id }
    assert_redirected_to project_path(assigns(:project))
  end
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

However, If I take the profile_name part out it recognises the ID. I still get a "no route matches" because theres no profile_name. Seems strange.

`1) Error:
ProjectsControllerTest#test_should_update_project:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:id=>"980190962", :project=>{:description=>"MyText", :title=>"MyString", :user_id=>"1"}, :controller=>"projects", :action=>"update"}
    test/controllers/projects_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:ProjectsControllerTest>'`